# Using the unique function without sorting the values and getting those rows

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to get **all the rows based on the unique values found in the third column and not sort them**.  see example below.
The index of the rows that I would keep would be row 1,2,3,5,7 (in that order)
I was thinking of using `unique([5 5 3 4],'stable')` (the 'stable' option seems to keep the index value order without sorting), but `Octave 4.0` which I'm using doesn't have the stable option how can a work around this?

Example array:

```
C=[
1, 103.4025175681402,    103.4104224840438,    0.007904915903608867;
2, 102.1231938014567,    102.1146017352405,    0.00859206621620956;
3, 97.5338137548381,    97.53996181901071,    0.006148064172606382;
4, 97.54468038366592, 97.53996181901071,    0.004718564655206592;
5, 93.76199482417094,    93.77030145885571,    0.008306634684771552;
6, 93.77539643924416,    93.77030145885571,    0.005094980388449244;
7, 106.976493571217,    106.9837463671074,    0.007252795890309471]
```

The final array I'm trying to get

```
D=
[
1, 103.4025175681402,    103.4104224840438,    0.007904915903608867;
2, 102.1231938014567,    102.1146017352405,    0.00859206621620956;
3, 97.5338137548381,    97.53996181901071,    0.006148064172606382;
5, 93.76199482417094,    93.77030145885571,    0.008306634684771552;
7, 106.976493571217,    106.9837463671074,    0.007252795890309471];

Code: I used thanks Brocodile to gives me the index `1,2,4,6,7` I'm trying to get the index `1,2,3,5,7`

C=[1, 103.4025175681402,    103.4104224840438,    0.007904915903608867;
2, 102.1231938014567,    102.1146017352405,    0.00859206621620956;
3, 97.5338137548381,    97.53996181901071,    0.006148064172606382;
4, 97.54468038366592, 97.53996181901071,    0.004718564655206592;
5, 93.76199482417094,    93.77030145885571,    0.008306634684771552;
6, 93.77539643924416,    93.77030145885571,    0.005094980388449244;
7, 106.976493571217,    106.9837463671074,    0.007252795890309471]

[~,i,~] = unique(C(:,3));
D = C(sort(i),:);
```

output is:

```
 1       103.40251756814      103.410422484044   0.00790491590360887
 2      102.123193801457       102.11460173524   0.00859206621620956
 4      97.5446803836659      97.5399618190107   0.00471856465520659
 6      93.7753964392442      93.7703014588557   0.00509498038844924
 7      106.976493571217      106.983746367107   0.00725279589030947
```

Please note this is just an example there will be hundreds of rows.
PS: I'm using octave 4.0 on ubuntu 64bit 16.04
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `unique` to get the indices of what is unique by assigning it to multiple variables.

```
[D,id,ic] = unique(C);
```

`id` here gives us the indices of the unique values that are saved do `D` in `C`. 
If you only want to check the second column for unique values, you can only check the second column with `unique(C(:,2))`.
What you want now are the indices of the unique rows (by column 2) in C; we can get them with `[~,i,~] = unique(C(:,2), "first")`. In your example this would give us:

```
    i = 
        5
        3
        2
        1
        7
```

Now we just need to `sort(i)` to get the indices in the right order, and then copy the unique rows into D:

```
D = C(i,:)
```

Long story short:
You can work around the lack of `'stable'` like this:

```
[~,i,~] = unique(C(:,2), "first");
D = C(sort(i),:);
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the index `1,2,4,6,7` not `1,2,3,5,7` I'll updated the question with the code I  used

Comment: I only use matlab, but from the documentation i think it is fixed by using `[~,i,~] = unique(C(:,2), "first");` in octave.